# How to block all access to some files except access from my HTML page (using htaccess)

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I have index.html in my site's root like `mysite.com/index.html`.

Then I have a folder called `fonts` like this `mysite.com/fonts`.

I need to allow access to the `fonts` folder and `.ttf` files inside it only from request that is sent by my html page. (in my `style.css` file I have `@font-face`)

---

I have searched a lot and the only solution I found was to redirect all requests to a `php` file and check the `http_referer` then if it was from my site, with function `readfile()` send that file to user.
[see php.net documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: Evaluating the http referrer is not a robust approach since it is completely controlled by the client side. I would suggest that you ask yourself why you actually want to restrict requests the way you describe it. It is a recurring question, typically asked by beginners... Think of it this way: you publish something via your http server. So why do you then want to suddenly restrict access again?

Comment: because that font is not free and I think restricting access is a good way to prevent it from being used by others who haven't purchased it.

Comment: You cannot really protect anything you publish. That just won't work. You are fighting windmills.

Comment: ok, thanks. but tell me if there is a way, at least to do something with it. anyway

Comment: You want to take a look at the attempts to prevent "image hotlinking". You tasks is the same, only not for images but for fonts. You can use apache's rewriting module for that: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html#blocked-inline-images

Comment: ok thanks, that helped in some way :)